# SQL Server: Unable to save import export package, but am on Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am confused.

Issue: SSIS ("SQL Server Import Export Wizard") should let me build a data import package and save it to a file, for easy re-running (converting to a task, etc.).

I want to save a package, but the tool always tells me "profile cannot be saved because your are not running SQL Standard Edition."

I know that the SSIS ("SQL Server Import Export Wizard") that, but I think I qualify.

Why is the save option not available?

I *am* connecting to an instance of standard (from connection properties in SSMS):

```
Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit)  (SQL 2005)
```

I have tried the SQL 2012 and 2014 client tools, and have the same experience on each.

How do I solve this?

(Is the tool detecting Express edition that I have locally?)

Comment: @billinkc If I follow you, it means I need to use the appro installer for client tools to get that client piece in licensed mode? (Next Q: Are client tools included in the main installer for server, or are client tools always in discrete client installer? -- I have always used the latter.)

Answer (score 2):

*<sub>Community Wiki answer created from an answer in the question comments by [billinkc](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2131/billinkc)</sub>*

---

The version of the DTS Wizard that is launched is or isn't licensed based on the installation. Here you can see that I am licensed for SSIS on my 2008 instance but not for the 2014 (because I only installed client tools):

[image: Screenshot]

You can have a valid SSMS install and even a BIDS/SSDT install, and still not be licensed for creating SSIS packages. Also, you might be connecting to a licensed Standard Edition box but the tools on your local machine would need to be Dev/Standard/BI/Enterprise/DW edition.