# SQL Server Client Tools: How can you tell what SQL edition the client tools are from?

Tags: sql-server

While working on [SQL Server: Unable to save import export package, but am on Standard Edition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/106968/6229) , the question came up:

We know how to ask SQL Server what edition it is. (Look at properties of server in SSMS, "select @@version" etc.). But how do we look at an install of client tools and tell what version the client tools are?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Management Studio's `Help > About...` menu. For example, I am running the latest build of SQL Server 2016 (CTP 2.1), and this is what my `Help > About` shows:

> [image]

If I click <kbd>Copy Info</kbd>, I get this in my clipboard:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio          13.0.300.44
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools        13.0.300.44
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)         10.0.10166.0
Microsoft MSXML                                 3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.10166.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                6.3.10166
```

There are no longer any "editions" of client tools, starting with SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1. Before that, there were only two editions: licensed and Management Studio Express. `Help > About` would yield that information as well, and [the title bar would say so too](http://img.softpicks.com.es/screenshots/SQL-Server-Management-Studio-Express.jpg).

Comment: But at least one tool (the data import/export tool) is restricted on express edition (it will not save an import profile). How do I detect this without actually using the tool?

Comment: @samsmith again, that shouldn't be true on modern versions. If you insist on using an old version like 2008 or 2008 R2, and you need to test for this programmatically, you'd have to check the binaries somehow (sorry, I don't know what to look for, to be honest). You should just make a specific version a low end requirement..